# If $x^3-3x+1$ has three real roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$, where $x_1<x_2<x_3$, then value of $\{x_1\}+\{x_2\}+\{x\}$ is?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

**$\{.\}$ represents fractional part function**

$$f’(x)=3x^2-3=0$$
$$\implies x=\pm 1$$

Function is maximum at $x=-1$ and minimum at $x=1$

$$f(-1)=2$$ and $$f(1) =-1$$

One root lies between $-1$ and $1$ and the others lie before and after the numbers respectively.

$$\{x_1\}+\{x_2\}+\{x_3\}$$
$$=(x_1+x_2+x_3)-([x_1]+[x_2]+[x_3])$$
$$3-([x_1]+0+[x_3])$$

I don’t know how far $x_1$ and $x_3$ are from $-1$ and $1$, so the value of their greatest integer can’t be determined. How do I proceed?

Comment: What is $f(-2)$? And $f(2)$?

Comment: How did you get $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$? Or the value of $[x_2]$?

Comment: Sum of all roots is not $3$. (You take the $x^2$ coefficient when using Vieta's formulas.) If $-1<x_2<1$ we could have $[x_2]=-1$.

Comment: By Vieta, the sum of the fractional parts must be an integer and by the rational root theorem, there is no integer root. Hence the answer must be $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the intermediate value theorem,If you care about $x=-2,-1,0,1,2$ you can find the answer
$$f(-2)\times f(-1)<0 \to \exists x_3|x_3 \in (-2,-1), f(x_3)=0\\ \to -2<x_3<-1 \to [x_3]=-2$$ also
$$f(0)f(1)<0 \to \exists x_2|x_2 \in (0,1), f(x_2)=0\\ \to 0<x_2<1 \to [x_2]=0 $$ also
$$f(1)f(2)<0 \to \exists x_1|x_1 \in (1,2), f(x_1)=0\\ \to 1<x_3< \to [x_3]=1$$ so
$$x^3+0x^2-3x+1=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=x^3-\underbrace{(x_1+x_2+x_3)}_{\to 0}x^2+...$$ note that sum of roots is zero
so $$=(x_1+x_2+x_3)-([x_1]+[x_2]+[x_3])=0-(-2+0+1)=1$$

Comment: @Aditya: note that sum of roots is zero ,not -3

Answer (score 1):

by trial and error and intermediate value theorem

**Observe** $f(0),f(1)$,,

$f(-1),f(-2)$,,

$f(1),f(2)$  are of opposite signs.

thus we can find the intervals of roots.

Let $x_1=a$, $x_2=-2+b$, $x_3=1+c$

but

$x_1+x_2+x_3=0$

or :$a+b+c=1$

Note: $a,b,c$denote the fractional part of $x_1,x_2,x_3$

Answer (score 0):

Easy to see that: $x_1\in(-2,-1),$ $x_2\in(0,1)$ and $x_3\in(1,2).$

Thus, since $\{x\}=x-[x],$ we obtain:
$$\{x_1\}+\{x_2\}+\{x_3\}=2+x_1+x_2+x_3-1=1.$$